# Convert output table to JSON

Tags: json

I need to format the default Accel-PPP output in JSON, but I am not an experienced programmer and would like an efficient command to gain processing time. I found this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243484/how-do-i-convert-the-output-of-ps1-to-json. But the default output is different from the above link and is as follows:

```
  ifname  | username |    calling-sid    | rate-limit  
----------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 pppoe0   | joao     | EC:22:80:A2:5E:D5 | 10240/1024  
 pppoe2   | pedro    | C0:4A:00:88:E5:29 | 5120/1024   
 pppoe4   | maria    | B0:4E:26:B1:75:7D | 5120/1024
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
  [  
   {  
      "username":"joao",
      "data":{  
         "ifname":"pppoe0",
         "calling-sid":"EC:22:80:A2:5E:D5",
         "rate-limit":"10240/1024"
      }
   },
   {  
      "username":"pedro",
      "data":{  
         "ifname":"pppoe2",
         "calling-sid":"C0:4A:00:88:E5:29",
         "rate-limit":"5120/1024"
      }
   },
   {  
      "username":"maria",
      "data":{  
         "ifname":"pppoe4",
         "calling-sid":"B0:4E:26:B1:75:7D",
         "rate-limit":"5120/1024"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: This is a matter of reading the data and re-writing it in a different (JSON) format. What language would you prefer?

Comment: I really like AWK, but I could not do it, if you can help me with it, I'm grateful.

Comment: you're probably going to have a hard time with AWK here, given all the special characters. It would be easier to use a language like python if that makes sense for you?

Comment: I've suffered from this myself, but it may be same python, or maybe perl.

Answer (score 0):

I've make a little shell script to print it in JSON format:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Script to convert output of accel-cmd to JSON format
# Author: lfelipe
# Since: 2019-02-12

# Return of accel-cmd
ACCEL_RETURN=$(accel-cmd show sessions username,ifname,calling-sid,rate-limit,state | grep -v 'calling-sid' | grep -v '+-----' | sed 's/ //g')

# To save JSON format in string
JSON="["

# Delimiter of for
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

# For each result
for USER in $ACCEL_RETURN
do
        USERNAME=`echo  ${USER} | cut -d '|' -f 1`
        IFNAME=`echo    ${USER} | cut -d '|' -f 2`
        SID=`echo       ${USER} | cut -d '|' -f 3`
        RATE=`echo      ${USER} | cut -d '|' -f 4`

        JSON+='{'

        JSON+='"username":"'${USERNAME}'",'

        JSON+='"data":{'
        JSON+='"ifname":"'${IFNAME}'",'
        JSON+='"calling-sid":"'${SID}'",'
        JSON+='"rate-limit":"'${RATE}'"'
        JSON+='}'
        JSON+='},'

done

# Default delimiter
IFS=$OLD_IFS

JSON+="]"

#Remove the last comma
JSON=`echo ${JSON%,*} ${JSON##*,}`

# Print JSON in string
echo "$JSON"

exit
```

Tested in CentOS 6.9 and validated JSON in jsonlint